# Expansion of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-series

I have an integral of the form
$$ I=\int_0^{\infty}{dx}\ln \bigg(1+\exp(-\frac{f(x)}{a})\bigg) $$ where $a$ is a positive constant and $f(x)$ is a regular and positive function such that $I$ is finite (for example: $f(x)=x$); moreover $f(x)=x+O(x^3)$ for $x \rightarrow 0$.  I have to expand this integral $I=c_0+c_1a+..+c_na^n+O(a^{n+1})$ for $a \rightarrow 0^+$, with the value of the integral beeing dominated by the behaviour of $f(x)$ near $0$.
Can anyone give me some hints or references to compute the first coefficients of this expansion?

Comment: Does the integral converge at infinity? Does not look so.

Comment: I've edited the question, $f(x)$ is such that $I$ is finite

Comment: how can it be finite?

Comment: It is an hypothesis.

Comment: I've edited my question: f(x) is positive and $I$ finite. An example: $f(x)=x$. The point is: how can i do the expansion? I had in mind this example: f(x)=x*g(x), where g(x) is posivite and bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ have the expansion $f(x)=x+c_3 x^3+c_4 x^4 +\cdots$, then define $y=x/a$ and you have
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}{dx}\ln \bigg(1+\exp\left(-\frac{f(x)}{a}\right)\bigg)$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \left[a\ln \left(1+e^{-y}\right)-\frac{a^3 c_3 y^3}{e^y+1}-\frac{a^4 c_4 y^4}{e^y+1}+{\cal O}(a^5)\right]\,dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{12} \pi ^2 a-\frac{7}{120} \pi ^4  c_3 a^3-\frac{45}{2} \zeta (5)c_4  a^4+{\cal O}(a^5).$$
The term of order $a^p$ has coefficient $-c_p\left(1-2^{-p}\right)p! \zeta (p+1)$, when $c_p$ is the coefficient of order $x^p$ in the expansion of $f(x)$.

Comment: Reminiscent of "Watson's Lemma"?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you give some details on how you obtain the expansion of the integrand?

Comment: @paul garrett-- Could you give some more details on this Lemma?

Comment: @John, google will find Watson's lemma, for example. I don't remember where I first saw it, but it appears early on in any book on "asymptotic expansions" (another keyword). I think Erdelyi's book does this, for example. I wrote up something with bibliographic pointers: linked to from my "intro to modular forms" page (but not depending on that stuff) at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/, under label "asymptotics of integrals somewhere on the page", precise link http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/02d_asymptotics_of_integrals.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma

Comment: @paul garrett  Thank you very much

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Thank you very much